# what is the meaning of this VBA code

Tags: vba, excel

I have a part of VBA code here,

what is the meaning of "-i" here ?

```
strCommand = Chr(34) & p_strPathConsole & Chr(34) & " -i " & Chr(34) & p_strPathDatabase & "\input.csv" & Chr(34)                         'Erstelle den Befehl zum Aufruf der Konsole
Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")                                        'Erstelle ein Objekt für Shell
intShellReturn = objShell.Run(strCommand, 0, True)                                  'Konsolenaufruf und warte bis Rückgabewert existiert
```

thanks in advance!

Comment: It is a string literal that is being attached to the rest of what is being put into the `strCommand` variable.

Comment: For what it's worth, although written in vba your question is about scripting and batch files. It has some meaning (I have seen it before), but I have no clue what. I just copy batch lines :)

Comment: My guess is it is a parameter to the program named in `p_strPathConsole`.

Answer (score 0):

Just as Tony Dallimore guessed, it seems to be a parameter (a in-line named parameter), "-i" may stand for "input" and the next string attached to it is the path of the *input file* which happen to be a *csv* file.